# Vue 2 Cli CSP Build Issue - Eval & new Function Problem

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

Due to CSP Requirements I have had to convert a static vue application within the Vue 2 CLI environment.

After reading a lot of online documentation I am aware that for CSP compliant vue you need to use Render functions and a runtime version of Vue.js

My problem is that after converting my old static vue application to the Vue CLI build process I am still getting a ***'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed*** message. I am not sure why this is the case, due to Vue 2's cli build process apparently using the CSP compliant runtime vue version, unless otherwise specified in the config file for webpack.

The  specific code causing the CSP error (there is only one instance of it) is found in the built/output vendor.js file.  The code causing the issue is:

```
function Ts(t, e) {
        try {
            return new Function(t)
        } catch (n) {
            return e.push({
                err: n,
                code: t
            }), D
        }
    }
```

I have looked far and wide to figure out why this non CSP compliant code is appearing in Vue's built vendor.js file. Any advice would be great. I have read all of Vue's main documentation on CSP, and should re-iterate that I used Vue 2 CLI for the build and conversion of the static app.

Answer (score 1):

For any other poor soul who have gone down the rabbit hole of Vue.js static to non-compiled CSP conversion, these 2 steps solved my issue:

1. Manually change csp\build\webpack.base.conf.js '$vue' property to the following:

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBWuF.jpg)

2. In your main.js file change vue instantiation to the following pattern, this is needed so the component will mount correctly with the runtime build [Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmvxL.jpg)